# Laravel 4, cannot update user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my form i have this
`{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'put', 'action' => array('UserController@update', $user->id))) }}`

And in my controller i have this

```
public function update($id)
{
    //Find brugeren
    $user = new User($id);
    $user->email    = Input::get("email");
    if ( Input::get("password") != ""){
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get("password")); 
    }
    $user->update();

}
```

Can any help me though this? I am getting this error:
`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/kampmann/public_html/test/laravel-master/app/controllers/UserController.php on line 79 and defined`

Answer (score 5):

You should be using the `find()` method to update your user and save it using `save()` method:

```
public function update($id)
{
    //Find brugeren
    $user = User::find($id); /// HERE!
    $user->email = Input::get("email");
    if ( Input::get("password") != ""){
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get("password")); 
    }
    $user->save();

}
```

Comment: I think you mean `$user->save()` instead of `$user->update()`

Comment: Yeah, there was more to fix. Thanx.

Comment: Thanks! This ended up fixing a problem I was having as well!